# Mathematica 8 Using Heun's Method/Improved Euler's Method

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[image]

```
Clear[x, y, h, k, FirstSlope, SecondSlope];
h = [Pi]; y[[Pi]] = 0;
dy[x_, y_] = (Cos[x] - 3 x^2 y)/x^3;
Do[{x[k] = [Pi] + h*(k - [Pi]),
   FirstSlope = dy[x[k], y[k]],
   SecondSlope = dy[x[k] + h, y[k] + h*FirstSlope], 
   y[k + [Pi]] = y[k] + (h*(FirstSlope + SecondSlope))/2}, {k, [Pi], 
   5[Pi]}] Table[{x[k], y[k]}, {k, [Pi], 5[Pi]}]; 
MatrixForm[%]
```

Above image is my error. I'm trying to use Heun's method and my problem is:

1) I want it to stop at `y[5 Pi]` but it keeps going. I can manipulate it so that it goes to `y[5 Pi]`, but I want to know why exactly it's doing this.

2) `y[k]` is not evaluating at k=pi,2pi,3pi, etc.

Comment: Please post your code in text form, so anyone wanting to answer doesn't need to retype it. thanks

Comment: And ... you forgot to define the function `y[x_]`

Comment: Sorry -- I'm new here!
Below is my code


Clear[x, y, h, k, FirstSlope, SecondSlope]; 
h = \[Pi]; y[\[Pi]] = 0; dy[x_, y_] = (Cos[x] - 3 x^2 y)/x^3;
Do[{x[k] = \[Pi] + h*(k - \[Pi]), FirstSlope = dy[x[k], y[k]], 
  SecondSlope = dy[x[k] + h, y[k] + h*FirstSlope], 
  y[k + \[Pi]] = y[k] + (h*(FirstSlope + SecondSlope))/2}, {k, \[Pi], 
  5 \[Pi]}]
Table[{x[k], y[k]}, {k, \[Pi], 5 \[Pi]}];
MatrixForm[%]

Comment: And I don't think defining y[x_] was the problem -- i think it has to do with the pi's.

Clear[x, y, h, k, FirstSlope, FirstSlope, SecondSlope];
h = 1; y[1] = 0.5; dy[x_, y_] = (y*Log[x])/Log[y];
Do[{x[k] = 1 + h*(k - 1), FirstSlope = dy[x[k], y[k]], 
  SecondSlope = dy[x[k] + h, y[k] + h*FirstSlope], 
  y[k + 1] = y[k] + (h*(FirstSlope + SecondSlope))/2}, {k, 1, 5}]
Table[{x[k], y[k]}, {k, 1, 5}];
MatrixForm[%] 

for instance, that works perfectly fine

Comment: Don't post code in comments; no-one's going to try to read it. Edit it into your question and format it using the facilities provided.